# AttributeConverter doesn't work with postgres jsonb, it report an error

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jsonb

AttributeConverter doesn't work with postgres jsonb, it report an error:
**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "cloud_reminder_parameters" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying**

My code is below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "scan_reminder_config")
public class ScanReminderConfig {

    @Convert(converter = ReminderParameters.ReminderParametersConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "cloud_reminder_parameters", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private ReminderParameters cloudReminderParameters;

    public static class ReminderParameters {
        private String timezone;

        @Converter(autoApply = true)
        public static class ReminderParametersConverter implements AttributeConverter<ReminderParameters, String> {

            private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            @Override
            public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final ReminderParameters reminderParameters) {
                try {
                    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(reminderParameters);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public ReminderParameters convertToEntityAttribute(final String dataValue) {
                try {
                    return objectMapper.readValue(dataValue, ReminderParameters.class);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Help, help, help, help

Comment: Error mentions "cloud_reminder_parameters" but you've only shown one column definition mapping for "onprem_reminder_parameters". Make sure you are looking and posting the right entity/mapping/converter, and maybe show the stack trace and code executing that hits the error, as well as the database table setup (what is the column in the DB and how was it created?)

Comment: @Chriscloud_reminder_parameters and cloud_reminder_parameters have the same data structure. And I use UserType now, and UserType can be used.